# Enter username and password into Dropbox login webview with Calablash android

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

I'm creating a test that is expected to login in dropbox. So the app starts the dropbox login webview.
With `query("webView css:'input'")` I'm able to retrieve the two inputs: login and password.

When I try to set the email field with `enter_text(query("webView css:'input'").first,"email@gmail.com")` I get the error:

`RuntimeError: map {"class"=>"text-input-input autofocus", "nodeType"=>"ELEMENT_NODE", "id"=>"pyxl14", "calSavedIndex"=>5, "html"=>"<input class=\"text-input-input autofocus\" type=\"email\" name=\"login_email\" id=\"pyxl14\">", "textContent"=>"", "rect"=>{"y"=>640, "x"=>52, "center_x"=>540, "height"=>89, "width"=>976, "top"=>220, "left"=>20, "center_y"=>685}, "nodeName"=>"INPUT", "webView"=>"NoResourceEntry-6"}, query failed because: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if it's not a cordovaWebView? Run `query "*"` in the calabash console and try to find the root webview element type in the output.

Comment: @RogérioPeixoto Actually I have both. The dropbox one is a WebView. Anyway, I'm able to get the input fields so that is not the problem, the problem is I can't set the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to set the text, it works but I can't understand what is the difference with the question's command.
The solution is:  `enter_text("webView css:'input[name=login_email]'", "email@gmail.com")`

Probably `enter_text` and `query` don't get along

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try restricting your query filter in the first parameter of the enter_text function using xpath:

```
enter_text("webView xpath:'//input[@id=\"pyxl14\"]'", "email@gmail.com")
```